# Manipulate and ExclusionsStyle

Tags: plotting, manipulate

How can I change `ExclusionsStyle` for a plot inside `Manipulate`?

Here's a sample that (though it shouldn't) seems to produce equivalent result to `ExlusionsStyle->{None}`:

```
Manipulate[
Plot[{1/(a - x), x/(x - b)}, {x, -10, 10},
Exclusions -> {b, a}, ExclusionsStyle -> {Dashed}], {a, -10, 10}, {b, -10, 10}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can give explicit `lhs == rhs` style exclusions to get dashed lines:

```
Manipulate[Plot[{1/(a - x), x/(x - b)}, {x, -10, 10}, 
    Exclusions -> {x == b, x == a}, 
    ExclusionsStyle -> Dashed], {{a, 0}, -10, 10}, {{b, 0}, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, seems like you _must_ rather than can..

Answer (score 3):

```
Manipulate[
   Plot[{1/(a - x), x/(x - b)}, {x, -10, 10}, Exclusions -> {b, a}, 
         ExclusionsStyle -> {Directive[Thickness[0.03], Orange]}
   ], 
   {a, -10, 10}, {b, -10, 10}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]